# Can't resolve 'module' with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

new guy here. I'm having an issue with using MongoDB with React.

This is the exact issue I'm having:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/resolve-from/issues/2

Not really sure if this is helpful, but here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "<myapp>",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "eslint": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.3",
    "mongodb-core": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "reset-css": "^2.2.1",
    "resolve-from": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

And the error message:

```
./node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in `'/Users/isaac/codetemp/<myapp>/node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from'`
```

However, I'm not exactly sure what that means or how I can fix it. I'm sure its a simple fix or I'm misunderstanding how MongoDB works, but I've been stumped all day on this one.

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: `Mongodb` is a NodeJS package, and you cannot bundle it for the client side

Comment: @Jiby Okay, so if I understand correctly, importing the server file in the main app will also bring the MongoDB package with it, which is not allowed. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you should not import your server file in your main client app